# Query to see how many times employees has worked same shifts

Tags: php, mysql

I run a management system where people who work different shifts are registered.

I'd like to be able to make a display of how many times each worker/volunteer worked same shifts, like this:

```
    |Amy|Carl|Max|
    |---|----|---|
Amy | X | 2  | 6 |
Carl| 2 | X  | 5 |
Max | 6 | 5  | X |
```

I was hoping you had some ideas how to form the query.
The only idea I've come up with so far is to make PHP create a custom query for each user.

```
Select count(common between user 1 and 2), count(common between user 1 and ...)
Select count(common between user 2 and 1), count(common between user 2 and ...)
```

etc..

I consider this an ugly way to do it and I am hoping there is some way of retrieving this data within a single query.

The database is stored like this:

Shifts

- ID
- From
- To

Working

- ID
- ShiftID
- UserID

Users

- ID
- Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to self-join the Working table:

```
SELECT a.UserID, b.UserID, count(a.ShiftID) AS common_shifts
FROM Working AS a
INNER JOIN Working AS b ON ((a.ShiftID = b.ShiftID) AND (a.UserID <> b.UserID))
HAVING common_shifts > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do a cross join where each row is compared to the other, and handle the case of userid=userid to put an X instead?